# insert records in batch using hibernate 4 and spring 3.x

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

java code:

```
EntityManager em1 = entityService.getEntityManager();
Query qury1 = em1.createNamedQuery(Constants.UNPROCESSED_CONTACTS);
List<Contact> contacts =  entityService.findByNamedQuery(qury1);
```

i have list of all contacts here , and i would like to add all contacts in batch of 100.
i am using hibernate 4 and spring 3.1 
my applicationContext is

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

how can i proceed further.
thanks in adv.

Comment: i have to insert all the records in db in batch of 100 i stuck with hibernate 4 config.

Answer (score 1):

JPA itself doesn't provide a batch insert facility, but hibernate does. I see you already have a `sessionFactory` bean. So you can just follow the example in the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html):

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

ScrollableResults customers = session.getNamedQuery("GetCustomers")
    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
int count=0;
while ( customers.next() ) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
    customer.updateStuff(...);
    if ( ++count % 20 == 0 ) {
        //flush a batch of updates and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

**For Bulk Insert:**

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
         session.flush();
       session.clear();
   }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

**And in hibernate XML configuration:**

```
<entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</entry>
```

Do these thing together you can insert much faster than previous type.